# Hide Lines from Matplotlib Plot without redrawing them?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a new issue with matplotlib and 'hiding' lineplots.

I have a wxFrame with a matplotlib plot and an cursor to give values. Works perfectly well.
In the plot are up to 13 lines and I want to show and hide them using checkboxes, this is working fine, too.

This is my code to 'redraw'

```
def Draw(self, visibility = None):
    self._axes.lines = []
    # if no visibility data, draw all
    if visibility is None:
        visibility = []
        for i in range(len(self._data)):
            visibility.append(True)
    else:
        # check if length match
        if len(self._data) != len(visibility):
            raise AttributeError('Visibility list length does not match plot count')
    # draw the lines you want
    for i in range(len(self._data)):
        if visibility[i]:
            plotName = 'FFD ' + str(i + 1)
            self._axes.plot(self.timebase, self._data[i], picker=5, label = plotName)
    #if there are any lines, draw a legend
    if len(self._axes.lines):
        self._axes.legend(prop={'size':9})

    #update the canvas
    self._canvas.draw()
```

But this results in the plot colors changing on every change. How can I have the colors stay? Any good ideas are appreciated (bad ones are also appreciated :) )!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list of colours from a colormap the same length as the number of lines you want to plot. You can do this with `cm.<any_cmap>(np.linspace(0,1,number_of_lines))`.

When you call `plot` set `color=colours[i]`. That way each plot will always be assigned the same colour, and even if its not plotted, the other lines' colours will not be affected.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm

def Draw(self, visibility = None):
    nlines = len(self._data)
    # Choose whichever colormap you like here instead of jet
    colours = cm.jet(np.linspace(0,1,nlines))  # a list of colours the same length as your data
    self._axes.lines = []
    # if no visibility data, draw all
    if visibility is None:
        visibility = []
        for i in range(len(self._data)):
            visibility.append(True)
    else:
        # check if length match
        if len(self._data) != len(visibility):
            raise AttributeError('Visibility list length does not match plot count')
    # draw the lines you want
    for i in range(len(self._data)):
        if visibility[i]:
            plotName = 'FFD ' + str(i + 1)
            # pick a colour from the colour list using the color kwarg
            self._axes.plot(self.timebase, self._data[i], picker=5, color=colours[i], label = plotName)
    #if there are any lines, draw a legend
    if len(self._axes.lines):
        self._axes.legend(prop={'size':9})

    #update the canvas
    self._canvas.draw()
```

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the only 'nice' solution. Still confused that there is no 'hide' or 'disable' :/

Comment: Tried it and works fine, but I get an undefined variable from import... will have to look into it, I hate to commit code with errors :/

Comment: did you find the root of your undefined variable?

Comment: no, but it works fine. the line 'colours = cm.jet(np.linspace(0,1,nlines))' is marked with 'undefined variable from import', also if i try other cmaps. But it works and to much to do to figure out, added an infamous #ToDo Tag

Comment: hmm, I get no such error when I run that, so I can't help any more, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bad one:

Try setting `alpha=0` to effectively hide a line doing something along the lines of `self._axes.lines[mylineindex].set_alpha(0.0)`. In this way you should only have to redraw that one line.

Comment: That works (I did the same by changing color to background color), but the lines are still pickable by the picker and appear in the legend :( I will edit the question according

Comment: is using `ax.legend().set_visible(False)` as done [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/legend_picking.html) an alternative?

Comment: Nope, as it still results in pickable lines. The would click a spot with to lines close together, Line one invisible, line to visible. An Arrow would appear with data about the invisible line one, but he wanted info about line two. If he only reads the tooltip text and not the header (saying line one), he could misinterpret data.